# When using scrollView.zoom I get different results from pressing a button to calling a function

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiscrollview

I am trying to zoom to a button on a UIScrollView. The first function is one that I run if I segue to the vc, the second is run from a button in the view.

When running the second function it goes perfectly and centres correctly

On the first however, despite being identical code, it has an offset in the x of about 40-50 pixels (Shows a point left of the button, not any part of it) although this offset changes dependent on the button.

```
func moveScrollviewToRoom(){
    scrollView.zoom(to: artButton.frame, animated: true)
}

@IBAction func moveScrollview(_ sender: Any) {
    scrollView.zoom(to: artButton.frame, animated: true)
}
```

The function was called here:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    if moveToRoom != "" {
        moveScrollviewToRoom()
       }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Cheers!

Comment: When are you calling `moveScrollviewToRoom()`? Likely, it's before auto-layout has finished setting up the view. Try moving it to `viewDidAppear()`.

Comment: Hi Don, it was called in the super.viewDidLoad() through an if statement.

I've updated the question to show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two points...

1 - Views and subviews have not yet been positioned by auto-layout in `viewDidLoad()`, so the `artButton.frame` will not be correct.

2 - Calling any function that animates a view from `viewDidLoad()` won't give the desired results, because the view is not even visible yet.

Move your call to `viewDidAppear()`:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    if moveToRoom != "" {
        moveScrollviewToRoom()
    }

}
```